# Need help dynamically removing checked item from ul in html

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

This is my first html project and I am trying to make a simple todo list. I have two buttons, an add and delete button. The add button works and displays whatever item I have the user enter into the input tag. Now I would like to remove any items from my list if they are checked and the user clicks the 'delete checked' button. I have some javascript written and this isn't working. Would anyone be able to point me in the correct direction on how to properly implement my delete button?

So in this screenshot, when the 'delete checked' button is pressed I would like for the 'eggs' item and 'oranges' item to be deleted.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ToDoList</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-cabable" content="yes"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
  font-weight: bold;

}

body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: thin dotted;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

input {
  text-align: center;
  width: wrap_content;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border: 2px solid rgb(128,128,128);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

button {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.deleteall {
  position: relative;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <head>
      <h1>
        ToDo-List
      </h1>
    </head>
    <form>
      <label>
        Title:
        <input id="newitem" type="text" placeholder="Tap to enter a new item&hellip;">
        <br>
        Details:
        <input id="detail" type="text" placeholder="Details of new item&hellip;">
        <br>
        Date:
        <input id="date" type="date" placeholder="year/month/day">
        <br>
        Time:
        <input id="time" type="time" placeholder="00:00">
        <br>
      </label>
      <button type="button" id="additem">
        Add
      </button>
      <button class="button deleteall" type="button" id="deleteitems">
        Delete Checked
      </button>
    </form>

    <ul id="todo-list-container">
    </ul>

    <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <!-- ITEM_NAME -->
      </label>
    </li>
    </script>

    <script>
    var addNewItem = document.getElementById("additem");
    var newItem = document.getElementById("newitem");
    var toDoListContainer = document.getElementById("todo-list-container");
    var itemTemplate = document.getElementById("item-template");
    var template = itemTemplate.innerText;
    var deleteAllItems = document.getElementById("deleteitems");

    addNewItem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var itemName = newItem.value;
      newItem.value = "";

      var itemHTML = template.replace("<!-- ITEM_NAME -->", itemName);
      toDoListContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', itemHTML);
    });

    deleteAllItems.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       var ul = document.getElementById("todo-list-container");
       var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i){
        if(items.checked == true){
          // remove item from list
          items.remove();
        }
       }

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `this isn't working` - in what way doesn't it work? any console errors? check the for loop inside the delete click handler, you have a number of issues, especially without knowing what `getElementsByTagName` actually returns

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working! Here's what I did.

1. Created Empty array called `toDoListData`.
2. Add an event to `addItem`, which adds the data to the `toDoListData` array then calls `refreshUIbasedOnArray()` function (will explain later what that does.)
3. Add an event to `deleteItems`, which loops through the array, and checks if there are any checked items in `toDoListContainer` children. If is checked, make index `i` in array equal `null`. (The array and `toDoListContainer` children have the same data.) Then call `refreshUIbasedOnArray()`.
4. Add an Event to `deleteAllItems`, which just empties the `toDoListData` array, and calls `refreshUIbasedOnArray()`.
5. `refreshUIbasedOnArray` function empties out `toDoListContainer` children (so it can repopulate later on). Then delete all `null` in `toDoListData` array. Next, loops through `toDoListData` array and creates the necessary elements, which is then appended to `toDoListContainer`.

Hope this is clear.

#### JSFiddle

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var detail = document.getElementById("detail");
var addNewItem = document.getElementById("additem");
var deleteItems = document.getElementById("deleteitems");
var deleteAllItems = document.getElementById("deleteAllItems")
var toDoListContainer = document.getElementById("todo-list-container");

var toDoListData = [];

addNewItem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var titleText = title.value;
  var detailText = detail.value;

  // If titleText, or detailText doesn't have any
  // text in it, then return; don't do anything
  if (!titleText || !detailText) return;

  toDoListData.push({
    title: titleText,
    detail: detailText
  });
  refreshUIbasedOnArray();
  title.value = '';
  detail.value = '';
});

deleteItems.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < toDoListData.length; i++) {
    if (toDoListContainer.children[i].firstElementChild.checked) {
      toDoListData[i] = null;
    }
  }
  refreshUIbasedOnArray();
});

deleteAllItems.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // Empty 'toDoListData' array
  toDoListData = [];
  refreshUIbasedOnArray();
});

function refreshUIbasedOnArray() {
  // Remove everything from 'toDoListContainer',
  // then repopulate it from the 'toDoListData' array

  toDoListContainer.innerHTML = "";

  // Reason for loops through the array backwards,
  // see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18165553/4861207 
  for (var i = toDoListData.length; i--;) {
    if (toDoListData[i] === null) {
      toDoListData.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < toDoListData.length; i++) {
    var listWrapper = document.createElement("li");
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    var text = document.createElement("div");

    checkBox.type = 'checkbox'

    text.innerHTML = toDoListData[i].title;

    listWrapper.appendChild(checkBox);
    listWrapper.appendChild(text);
    toDoListContainer.appendChild(listWrapper);
  }
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  font-weight: bold;
}
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
form {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: thin dotted;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
  width: wrap_content;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border: 2px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
button {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.deleteall {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h1>ToDo-List</h1> Title:
<input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Tap to enter a new item&hellip;">
<br>Details:
<input id="detail" type="text" placeholder="Details of new item&hellip;">
<br>
<button type="button" id="additem">
  Add
</button>
<button class="button" type="button" id="deleteitems">
  Delete Checked
</button>
<button class="button" type="button" id="deleteAllItems">
  Delete All
</button>

<ul id="todo-list-container">
</ul>
```